# Custom validator of FormArray in Angular run too many times

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In Angular 6, I used FormBuilder to create a Form like this:

```
formData = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  description: new FormControl(''),
  listSubItem: this.formBuilder.array([], ValidationService.noDuplicateSubItemName),
});
```

In the form, there are around 100 item of listSubItem.
However, if there is any change in the screen, the function ValidationService.noDuplicateSubItemName will be called 100 times.

Is there anyway to call it only 1 time in case any change in screen.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.

Comment: You can use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to only do change detection when you want to. It can greatly improve performance so it's definitely  worth it!

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on how your noDuplicateSubItemName validator work, but you can add "global validator" on your "form"

```
formData = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  description: new FormControl(''),
  listSubItem: this.formBuilder.array([]),
}, { validator :  ValidationService.noDuplicateSubItemName});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without seeing the template but i'll try.

I guess you're displaying your array with a *ngFor directive in your template, this means that everytime your array gets updated the whole DOM managed by the *ngFor is rendered again and every check is made for every object modified (so everything).

You can try to improve performance in your template by adding "trackBy" to the *ngFor that manages the data array you're showing.

```
<div *ngFor="let arrayElement of arrayElements; trackBy: trackElementByFn"> test <div>
```

and in you component.ts you have to add:

```
trackElementByFn(index: number, item: string): number {
    return index;
}
```

Now when you change the collection, Angular can track which items have been added or removed according to the unique identifier and create or destroy only the items that changed.

For more information check this [article](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5) on trackBy.